# Display rows with a specific ID from all tables in a database in PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a big database with like 5+ tables and lot of data within.

For each row of data I have a userid as one of the field. I have it this way so that can identify which data belongs to which userid.

Now how do I display out all the data from all the tables with a specific userid?

I have tried some examples which i found online which displays out all the data using information_schema.tables but how do I only display from a particular userid?

Comment: if you post summary of your tables, people can help you better

Comment: this one will be achieved by the JOIN Queries . if u have any doubt please see this link.http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32

Answer (score 0):

You have to use where clause in your mysql statement

**where userid = this**

put this at end of your statement

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no simple way how to do this, you can:

#### Run multiple queries:

Run one query for each type of table (articles, comments, posts... ):

```
display_articles_from_select( 'SELECT FROM articles WHERE user_id ... ');
display_comments_from_select( 'SELECT FROM comments WHERE user_id ... ');
```

#### [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

This option is available only if columns in each table are "compatible" to each other, for example each table has `title` and `text` field.

```
(SELECT title, text FROM articles WHERE used_id = ...)
UNION
(SELECT header AS title, text FROM comments WHERE used_id = ...)
...
```

#### [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

And if you have database schema which allows this you can simply join tables, but without detailed DB scheme info I can't provide an example nor confirm that this is possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

basic syntax for selecting all data from different tables:

table1, table2, table3

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* 
FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2, table3 as t3
WHERE
t1.userid = '1' and t2.userid = '1' t3.userid = '1'
```

You can see [this site](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=5) for more information

Answer (score 0):

this one will be achieved by the JOIN Queries . if u have any doubt please see this link.http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32 or o/w give me the table fields i will update.

and i hope this will help you..

for example,

```
1). mysql> SELECT * FROM products;
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | product_name | manufacturer |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | Shoes        | Company1     |
|  2 | Laptop       | Company2     |
|  3 | Monitor      | Company3     |
|  4 | DVD          | Company4     |
+----+--------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)





 2). mysql> SELECT * FROM buyers;

    +----+------+------------+----------+
    | id | pid  | buyer_name | quantity |
    +----+------+------------+----------+
    |  1 |    1 | Steve      |        2 |
    |  2 |    2 | John       |        1 |
    |  3 |    3 | Larry      |        1 |
    |  4 |    3 | Michael    |        5 |
    +----+------+------------+----------+
```

this will be the output.

```
mysql> SELECT buyers.buyer_name, buyers.quantity, products.product_name FROM buyer
s LEFT JOIN products ON buyers.pid=products.id where buyers.id=1;
+------------+----------+--------------+
| buyer_name | quantity | product_name |
+------------+----------+--------------+
|John        |        1 | Laptop       |
+------------+----------+--------------+
```